# Why localhost:8081/share can not be open?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to do alfresco [tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#configuring-the-custom-model-in-alfresco-share). Under "Configuring the Custom Model in Alfresco Share" header I reached "Configuring the Custom Model in Alfresco Share". Then I run:

```
mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war
```

Both for `content-tutorial-repo` and `content-tutorial-share`. Both `repo` and `share` started normally. But path `http://localhost:8081/share` redirects me to `http://localhost:8081/share/page/` and to `http://localhost:8081/share/page/user/admin/dashboard` after login. But tutorial says:

> Now open your browser and point it to http://localhost:8081/share. Log in using admin/admin and let’s see what’s different.
>   What’s different is that the “is sub-type” dropdown in the rule configuration panel now has our custom types and the “has aspect” dropdown now has our custom aspects.

But I see only dashboard no "Define Rule" as it shown on tutorial. What is wrong? How to open true `/share` path on alfresco?

Comment: There is an interceptor that redirect the /share requests to /share/page if the user is not connected otherwise it should redirect to /share/page/user/{username}/dashboard. And concerning the rules management, follow @imagine answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define rules for folder, so:

- click [Repository] menu,
- choose some folder and click [View Details]
- finally click [Manage Rules]

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/library-folder-rules-define-create.html

Comment: It seems that tutorial miss some paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you all are doing well. 
I have two tomcat instances on my machine(apache-tomcat-7.0.5 and apache-tomcat-6.0.24).To run tomcat 7 I have made below changes in server.xml:-

shutdown port is changed from 8005 to 8006 
connector port changed from 8080 to 8081 
redirect port changed from 8443 to 8445 
For AJP port changed from 8009 to 8010

Thank You.